# when I use tab on rsync and remote pc magical characters happear in display

Tags: rsync, console, display, character-encoding

Simple.
I have the file "longname.server" on remote pc, I want to copy on my pc, but..I don't remind the name because is long and I use tab completion.

```
\rsync -avP  remote:^[\\\[0\\\;longname.server^[\\\[0m\\\^M
```

Strange characters appear on display after I press the tab key to complete name, what to check?
Distro is Slackware 15.0.

I see this problem happen on Slackware 15.0 but not in 14.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround found.
I start bash without reading the rc files

```
bash --norc
```

now the command works

Then I edit bashrc and I delete those lines which cause problems

```
# Append any additional sh scripts found in /etc/profile.d/:
for profile_script in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
  if [ -x $profile_script ]; then
    . $profile_script
  fi
done
unset profile_script
```

so the problem was on one of profile scripts
the bash-completion script I think

edit2: on another Slackware 15.0 pc the problem don't appear
so probably this other pc is misconfigured